# CommandText Not Runtime error 1004 in office 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that should update the date in a sql query of a connection in excel. The date determines the table the data will come from. The code works without a problem in office 2016 on windows 10. However, I get runtime **error**

> 1004: "application-defined or object-defined error”"

on .CommandText line when I run the same macro in office 2013 on windows 8.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

```
Sub change_date()

Dim a As String, x As String, year As String, month As String, day As String, datebox As Variant

'Get the day, month and year from name of the workbook
x = ActiveWorkbook.Name
year = Mid(x, 1, 4)
month = Mid(x, 5, 2)
day = Mid(x, 7, 2)

'Ask user if he/she wants to change the date
    datebox = InputBox("Is the report date " & _
    day & "." & month & "." & year & _
    "?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "If not, please enter the report date below as YYYY-MM-DD and click 'OK'." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "If that is the correct date, click 'OK' or 'Cancel' without entering anything below")
If datebox = "" Then
    x = year & "-" & month & "-" & day
Else
    x = datebox
End If

'Update the query with the report date
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("postgres y_original_customer_info").ODBCConnection
a = "SELECT * FROM public.f_customers_with_pllm_and_gkh('"
a = a & x
a = a & "')"

'Following line gives Runtime error 1004
.CommandText = a

'Following also gives error
'.CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM public.f_exposures_with_sllp_and_cqs('" & x & "')")

.Refresh
End With
End Sub
```

I can't understand why the code doesn't work in office 2013. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just a note: `Dim a, x, year, month, day As String` only declares `day As String` all others are `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytables-object-excel perhaps this can be of help to you.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for the warning, I did specify everything as you said. Luuklag thanks, but it didn't help with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these two:

1. Write `Debug.Print a` before the `.CommandText` in both versions and make sure that the results are the same
2. Check the `ODBCConnection` in both files. E.g., rebuild it in both places.

(3.) The comment of @Peh is an important point. You need to declare each variable type explicitly. E.g. `Dim a as Long, x as Variant, year as Long, month as Long, day as String`

Comment: 1. Debug.Print gives same result in both versions.  
2. Didn't help with the problem, still getting the same error in Office 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was apparently caused by multiple pivots using the same connection. More details: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25840229/How-do-I-programmatically-changing-the-Command-Text-property-of-a-Connection-in-MS-Excel-2007.html

Changing the connection type from ODBC to OLEDB before updating the command text and then changing it back helped solve the issue.

I added following code:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches(1)
If .QueryType = xlODBCQuery Then
    strConnection = Replace(.Connection, "ODBC;DSN", "OLEDB;DSN", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
    .Connection = strConnection
    'Update the sql query
    .CommandText = strSQL

'Change connection back to ODBC
    strConnection = Replace(.Connection, "OLEDB;DSN", "ODBC;DSN", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
    .Connection = strConnection

'If connection is not ODBC, then update the query right away
Else 
    .CommandText = strSQL

End If
```